# How to stretch content outside the page layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create [this design](https://i.postimg.cc/wxSJG7pt/Rss-feed-client.png) where the content stretch left and right of the browser window.

This is what I've tried:

```css
.ig-feed{
  position: relative;
  height: 664px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ig-feed .ig-feed__feed-container{
  height: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -146px;
  right: -146px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="ig-feed">
  <div class="ig-feed__feed-container">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My [design](https://i.postimg.cc/5yGmP3mj/Screen-Shot-2022-05-03-at-1-23-17-PM.png) takes a lot more space between the images due to `justify-content: space-between;`

How should I make it just take `20px` between the images with stretch all the way to left and right.

My [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a54fon3h/)

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by  stretch all the way to left and right with respect to images?

Comment: I meant to position the container all the way to left and right but at the same time, I want to make sure there should be 20px gap between the images.

Comment: You can read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `margin-right` and depends on your screen size you can give responsive `width` values for your images

```
.ig-feed__feed-container a {
  margin-right: 20px;
 }
```

```css
.ig-feed{
  position: relative;
  height: 664px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ig-feed .ig-feed__feed-container{
  height: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -146px;
  right: -146px;
  display: flex;
}

.ig-feed__feed-container a {
  margin-right: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="ig-feed">
  <div class="ig-feed__feed-container">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a gap property with a value (adding 20px as you mentioned) to add a gap between them. I believe this is all you are looking for based on the design mentioned.

```css
.ig-feed{
  position: relative;
  height: 664px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ig-feed .ig-feed__feed-container{
  height: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -146px;
  right: -146px;
  display: flex;
  gap:20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="ig-feed">
  <div class="ig-feed__feed-container">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="Insta Image"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the gap wouldn't work with `justify-content: space-between;` on the desktop screen.

Comment: did you run the code snippet? its working